# Replacing strings in PowerShell: "-"

Tags: powershell, replace, powershell-ise

I know this topic has been widely discussed here, but I am newbie on PowerShell and facing some hurdles to replace a symbol in the table.

In the picture below there some symbols **"-"** in the numeric column **"PRECOMEDIODISTRIBUICAO"**.

[image]

I ran the following code in order to replace such symbols to "0" number:

```
$file = Import-Csv -Path $file -Delimiter "`t" | 
Select PRECOMEDIODISTRIBUICAO | ForEach {$_ -Replace "\?_", 0}
```

But got the following result:

[image]

I tried different ways to replace **"-"** symbol to **0**, but got no success.
For example:  **"-"**,  **"-  "**,  **"\ -  "** , **"  -   "**  generated no correction.

Do you have a better idea how to replace such string?

Comment: `-Replace '\-', '0'`

Comment: If you want to replace the `-` character, why are you replacing `\?_`?

Comment: Please don't post pictures, where text would serve as well.

Comment: @LotPings Sure! I'll avoid it...

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Import-Csv -Path $file -Delimiter "`t" | ForEach {

    $_.PRECOMEDIODISTRIBUICAO = $_.PRECOMEDIODISTRIBUICAO -Replace '-', '0'
    $_
}
```

Your `Select PRECOMEDIODISTRIBUICAO` is (should be!) throwing away the other columns, and your replace on `$_ -replace` is trying to cast the whole object and all its properties into one string, then do the replace, then not save the replaced text anywhere. I don't know what the `\?` in the regex is doing, but it doesn't look necessary.

Comment: In case there **could** be negative numbers, I'd `-Replace '^-$','0'`

Comment: That's weird...the same error persisted even after declaring the column name.

Answer (score 3):

You can dynamically modify strings using code below. 'l' means label and e stand for expression. In the expression you do almost anything with the passed value. In this example replace '-' by 0

```
Import-Csv -Path $file -Delimiter "`t" |Select @{l="PRECOMEDIODISTRIBUICAO";e={$_.PRECOMEDIODISTRIBUICAO -replace '-', 0}}
```